# How to get count 0 using group by if record not exist in the same table?

Tags: group-by, count

I need some expert advice please.

I have a table with Employees and eCodes in SQL server. I want to get the count of eCodes for each employee but in some cases an employee doesn't have a certain eCode.

Where the eCode is missing for an employee I want to return zero.

```
SELECT Employee, eCode, Count(*) cnt FROM Test
Group By Employee, eCode
Order by Employee, eCode
```

The above SQL gives me following output

[image]

David is missing eCode X and Y, which Gary and Tony has. How can I return zero for its count.
Similarly Gary and Tony is missing F and G and I want to get zero for those two.

I can use some help here.

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Does some table with all possible `eCode` values exists? use it as a base. If not - gather this list from another copy of source table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should accomplish what you're looking for but this assumes all of your `eCodes` exist at least for one record in your `Test` table. Otherwise you can replace the `Test` table instance on the right side of the `CROSS JOIN` in the `CTE` below with your source table of `eCodes`:

```
WITH CTE_EmployeeECodes AS -- Gets a distinct list of all Employee and eCode combinations
(
   SELECT DISTINCT E.Employee, EC.eCode
   FROM Test AS E
   CROSS JOIN Test AS EC
)

SELECT EEC.Employee, EEC.eCode, COUNT(T.eCode) AS cnt
FROM CTE_EmployeeECodes AS EEC
LEFT JOIN Test AS T -- Left join allows us to keep all records from our source Employee & eCode combinations CTE, but T.eCode will be NULL for the eCodes an employee has 0 instances of
    ON EEC.Employee = T.Employee
    AND EEC.eCode = T.eCode
GROUP BY EEC.Employee, EEC.eCode
ORDER BY EEC.Employee, EEC.eCode
```

Comment: Thanks J.D. I need to brush up my CROSS JOIN :)

Comment: @FaridSiddiqui No problem! :)

Comment: Nice response! If I'm not mistaken, there seems to be a small syntax error in the CASE statement. Doesn't the `END` belong inside the `SUM()` function? Like: `[...] SUM(CASE WHEN T.eCode IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS [...]`?

Comment: @fujiu Yes, good catch! I just fixed it. Sorry I usually type up my answers on my phone and occasionally miss things.

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN T.eCode IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)` can be simplified to `COUNT(T.eCode)`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Good point! Updated. 